# Cargo error: unable to get packages from source

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-cargo

```sh
error: failed to download `adler v1.0.2`

Caused by:
  unable to get packages from source

Caused by:
  failed to parse manifest at `/home/actionanand/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/adler-1.0.2/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  could not parse input as TOML

Caused by:
  unexpected character found: `\u{0}` at line 1 column 1
```

Rust `.toml` file was full of red line when we add new dependency

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the crash of internal package (say cargo)

we can solve this by following the steps

1. Please clear the cargo `registry`

```sh
rm -rf /home/username/.cargo/registry/
```

2. And follow the proceedure shown after this, if you use old version

For the reference, I've given the proceedure also below:

```sh
If you are trying to migrate from the previous edition (2018), the
process requires following these steps:

1. Start with `edition = "2018"` in `Cargo.toml`
2. Run `cargo fix --edition`
3. Modify `Cargo.toml` to set `edition = "2021"`
4. Run `cargo build` or `cargo test` to verify the fixes worked

More details may be found at
https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/editions/transitioning-an-existing-project-to-a-new-edition.html
```

You may need to to add `--allow-no-vcs` sometimes (it'll be prompted by the terminal) as below

```sh
cargo fix --edition --allow-no-vcs
```

Comment: Instead of removing the whole registry, one can just delete the `.cargo-ok` file of the offending package, for example `/home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/shlex-0.1.1/.cargo-ok`.